# We're in public beta!

Tags: discussion

[image]

That means:

- We will be listed on the main SE page
- Our Q&A will be Googleable

What else?

Answer (score 9):

> What else?

- [Privilege requirements are higher](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)
- Anyone can sign up without going through the Area 51 proposal first
- Moderators will be elected in a pro-tempore election soon
- Meta is now officially referred to as Operations Research Beta Meta
- **THIS PLACE IS EVEN MORE AWESOME!**

Answer (score 6):

One more to add. Not sure if this is new to public beta, but I noticed it for the first time today: We now have a [magic link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/504785).

In particular, on another SE site, **in a comment to a question or answer, you can type `[or.se]`** and it will "magically" be replaced with [Operations Research](https://or.stackexchange.com/).